# Application of conservation of momentum to this system has absurd implications

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, spring, string

The system, **everything shown in the picture (table, pulley, spring, string, blocks, wall),** was initially at rest, with spring unstretched. Friction is absent everywhere, and spring, string, and pulley are massless. So initial momentum, $P_i=0.$ Now after some time the objects $A$ and $B$ of masses $m$ and $2m$ have velocities $v\hat{i}$ and $-v\hat{j}$, respectively. The final momentum of the system shown in picture, in $\hat{i}$ direction is $P_f=mv\hat{i}$. Now there is **no external force in $\hat{i}$ direction**, so I can apply conservation of momentum. Hence $P_i=P_f=mv\hat{i}=0.$ Hence $v=0.$ But that is absurd. According to this, the object should not have any velocity in $\hat{i}$ direction at any time. But of course, this is contrary to our common experience, so there must have been some error in my calculations (or derivation) but I am not able to find it.

I guess that the tension due to the string on the block $A$ is due to gravity, hence it can be counted as an external force. But still, the string and everything in the picture is part of our system. So should I consider the tension to be external or internal?

[image: djd]

Comment: There are very obvious external forces on the system, both horizontal and vertical

Comment: By Jove, of course, there is no external force in the horizontal direction if we consider the tension on $A$ to be internal.

Comment: What about the spring? What about gravity?

Comment: Spring and wall are part of our system and gravity is acting vertically.

Comment: If the system is the spring, string, and masses then there are external forces from: the wall, the floor, the pulley, and gravity. The wall also has forces acting on it from the ground.

Comment: Then there is an external force acting on the wall? If not then you need to consider the momentum of the wall as well.

Comment: The velocity of the wall is zero. Hence its momentum is zero.

Comment: There is a rightward force acting from the pulley drum on the system. This is what explains the change in momentum of the system rightward.

Comment: Pulley is also part of the system.

Comment: Ok but what is keeping the wall still? An external force needs to do that.

Comment: The wall is accelerating from an inertial frame (suppose a point in space) but from the reference of the ground it is not moving, because the ground with the wall is accelerating as well. Now since our frame is an accelerating one, so we cant apply conservation momentum and this is my mistake. To find the velocity I should apply COE (energy). Thanks! Good Day.

Comment: If the pulley is part of the system, then the pin joint acting from the pulley support on the pulley supplies the rightward force that is responsible for the change in rightward momentum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget about the Earth. In the vertical direction, the system of the masses A and B move down, and the Earth ever-so-slightly moves up. Similarly, in the horizontal direction, because of the rope in the pulley, a force is directed to the table which may be fixed to the Earth.

You'll find a similar paradox if you push yourself away from a wall. You'll have momentum afterwards, and if you forget the Earth, you'll think momentum was not conserved.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wonder how you were able to find the mistake so fast. Have you seen a similar mistake earlier? If not then what was your train of thoughts?

Comment: Have you ever heard the joke, "when Chuck Norris does push-ups he pushes the Earth down"? For me, when I think about 'equal/opposite forces' and conservation of momentum, I frequently remember that many motions on Earth push back on the Earth, because of this joke.

Comment: Another way to say that is: an external force changes the system’s overall momentum. So it is not conserved when external force is applied. We dont always have to show that the momentum of the universe was not changed by our experiment.